# Global variable for updating UI from App.js

Tags: reactjs

I have defined my global variable in index.js

```
window.$hideHome = false;
```

I am using this global variable in my NavBar

```
<Link to="/home" className={window.$hideHome ? "hideHome" : ""}>Home</Link>
```

In my App.js I have this method which is called every time the page has changed

```
history.listen((newLocation, action) => {
      if(condition) {
           window.$hideHome = false;
      }
});
```

I can see my global variable does in fact change from true to false, but my Link in my NavBar still appears and here is the CSS for it:

```
.hideHome { display: none !important; }
```

My NavBar is a class that extends Component, and my link is inside return() which is inside render() if that helps.
If I have my window.$hideHome outside of my history.listen, it does work.

Basically what I am trying to accomplish is to hide the Home button in my Nav on the whole site when someone is on a certain page.

Answer (score 0):

Here your global variable will be changed as expected. But in React the DOM renders when state value change. Here your Global variable is not set as state variable as a result your dom is not getting rendered.

If you have data on which your application state depends, that data should be kept in React state somehow. That is, rather than having a global variable that gets updated, just store that data in state. In that case, you could have that state in your parent component, or in a context, and it could be passed to whatever needs it.

If you really do need this to be a global variable that is not stored in state, then you can have a useState hook in the parent component that will mirror your global variable. Pass the setState function to the child that updates the global variable, and have it update the state with the same value in your function that updates the global variable. Then pass the state to the other child that needs the state.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).